# Create presentation with entire JSON on Google Slides API

Tags: json, google-apis-explorer, google-slides-api

Hello everyone (sorry for my english)

I have a problem with Google Slides API, I need to duplicate a Google Slides Document from an account to an another (so I can't use Google Drive API with the function "copy").

For that, I used Google Slides API to retrieve a JSON Object (Presentation) on client-side and send to my server (nodejs).

In my server-side application, I send the Presentation Object to anyone and the client can store it in Google Drive (always with Google Slides API).

But the problem is when the client send the Presentation Object (with all fields) to Google Slides API (presentations.create method), it just create a naked Google Slides document without properties include in my requests.

I need to store an entire Google Slides document but I can't do that and I don't know why.

I spent all day with this issue, please can you help me :) ?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Slides API only creates empty presentations via presentations.create(), unfortunately. Only the title is taken from that input object.

For a cross-account copy, Drive's copy API is likely your best bet. If you have write access to the source presentation in Drive, one option is to share it with the destination account first using the [Drive permissions.update API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/update) and then using copy. Another option is to try an export then import.